# docusign_rest gem not populating tab from template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docusignapi

I am trying to test the docusign_rest gem for possible integration into my rails app.  I have set up the gem and configured it with my username, password, and integrator key.  I have set the version of the api to 'v2' and checked all the of the names of both the signers and the tab fields multiple times.  Here is the code I am using to make the request:

```
 response = c.create_envelope_from_template(
   status: 'sent',
   email: {
     subject: "Test email subject",
     body: "Test email body",
   },
   template_id: template["templateId"],
   signers: [ 
     {
       embedded: false,
       name: "Name",
       email: 'example@gmail.com',
       role_name: "Signer1",
       tabs: {
         textTabs: [
           {
             tabLabel: "\\*address",
             value: "123 Example St.",
             locked: true
           }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

The request gets sent and the envelope gets sent but the 'address' field is not populated. Is there anything I am doing obviously wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `embedded` is not a valid property for the request body, first thing I'd try is removing that.  Next are you absolutely positive that the tab label is "address" without spaces? (it's case sensitive)

Comment: Also, is the user being correctly matched to the template role named "Signer1"?  Are they inheriting all the tabs for that role but the text fields simply aren't populating?

Comment: @Ergin Sorry for the slow response.  I am using the DocusignRest gem which was why I had that embedded flag.  I removed it and double checked both the template role name and the tab label and both are correct.  I even remade the template to be sure.  All the tabs for that role are being inherited they are just not populating at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself by modifying the gem to inspect the request.  With the docusign_rest gem, the documentation on the github page is incorrect.  The tabs dictionary should not be there and the items in this specific request should be underscore separated instead of camel case. Therefore, the actual request would look something like:

```
response = c.create_envelope_from_template(
  status: 'sent',
  email: {
   subject: 'Test email subject',
   body: 'Test email body',
   },
  template_id: template["templateId"],
  signers: [
     {
       embedded: false,
       name: 'Name',
       email: 'example@gmail.com',
       role_name: 'Signer1',
       text_tabs: [
          {
            label: 'Address',
            name: 'Address',
            value: '123 Example Street.',
          }
      ]
    }
  ]
)
```

This request will allow you with the gem and v2 of the api to create an envelope from a template and prepopulate any fields.  All other field types go the same way as the text_tabs array.

Comment: I just sent in a PR to fix the documentation https://github.com/jondkinney/docusign_rest/pull/45

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `signers` node in you request body to `templateRoles`.  When you use templates in DocuSign instead of specifying the signers and their types and tabs, you assign them to existing template roles that are configured in the template.  That's why no signer types should be specified in this call, just the template roles that each recipient will get matched to, and the values of any tabs you want to populate.

I've never used Ruby before so there might be some formatting or syntax issues I'm missing here, and I also have never seen the ruby gem you're referring to so not sure how stable or correct that code is.  But basically this is what I think you need to do...

Right now you have:

```
status: 'sent',
   email: {
     subject: "Test email subject",
     body: "Test email body",
   },
   template_id: template["templateId"],
   signers: [ 
     {
             ...
```

Try changing `signers` to `templateRoles`, like so:

```
status: 'sent',
   email: {
     subject: "Test email subject",
     body: "Test email body",
   },
   template_id: template["templateId"],
   templateRoles: [ 
     {
             ...
```

The resulting http request body that you need to construct should look something like the following (in JSON format):

```
{
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template",
    "templateId": "ABCD1234",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "firstperson@email.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "roleName": "Template Role Name goes here",
            "tabs": [
                {
                    "textTabs": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "\\*address",
                            "value": "432 Sorrento Dr.",
                            "locked": "true"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Lastly, the DocuSign API Walkthrough for requesting a signature from a template is a great resource for sending from a template so this might help too.  There's sample code for making this api call in 6 different languages (unfortunately Ruby is not one of them):

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromTemplate

Comment: the method on the gem is looking for a signers array and throws an exception when I change that value to templateRoles.  I am checking what request it is actually making right now.